# Is the following correct ? (sign in Chinese seen in Thailand)

Tags: mandarin, sentence-structure

It says:
请勿餐和饮料进来
Personally I would say:
请把餐和饮料拿不进来

Comment: it would be better to write 请勿带餐点或饮料入内

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't think that's good enough. From Chinese slogans' use condition it's better to be“请勿自带餐品（食品）和饮料入内” or “禁止外带餐品饮料”

Comment: 外带 means 'take out'

Comment: You are right. “携带”  is more suitable